# Flash Buttons Not Working On Website

Tags: flash, web

I have built a flash header for my website. http://www.jjwallace.info/

While accessing with the URL www.jjwallace.info/

My buttons to the blog and portfolio do not work.

While accessing with the URL http://jjwallace.info/

Everything works fine.

I have searched everywhere for this problem but i am unsure what is going on.

I am guessing my .htaccess file maybe be limiting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you use absolute urls

`getURL("http://jjwallace.info/portfolio", "");`

Use relative instead

`getURL("/portfolio", "");`

And use relative path to swf in html too

`<param name="movie" value="/jj_banner.swf">`

Comment: wont work, cause the header will reference /blog while in /blog

Comment: what do you mean 'reference'? Your header seen the same in all urls, current position doesn't highlight, so i don't see any potential problem. Write usecase, your expectations and the facts...

Comment: ok i changed the relative path for the arcade and it seems to be working now :)